# Can all CSS written with pre-pocessors be converted back to standard CSS?

Tags: html, css, compass-sass

Given the following piece of CSS written with SASS Compass:

```
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  .open-menu {
     display: none; 
  }
  .close-menu {
     display: block;
  }
  .main-header {
    width: 80%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write it in stadard CSS standard and still have the same styling effect?

The above piece of code is from Codepepen. When I select NOT to use any pre-processor, generates a CSS that breaks the styling.

What would be the standard CSS format of this code if it's possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Just run SASS over it and look at the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran that through a SASS processor and got this:

```
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
    width: 80%; 
}
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap .open-menu {
    display: none; 
}
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap .close-menu {
    display: block; 
}
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap .main-header {
    width: 80%;
    left: 20%; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I made a mistake. I can see now that Codepen generates it back properly as well.